# Oracle database not sort dates properly using PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I have an oracle database with information and I want to make a simple search site where users can search necessary information from database. All is ok, but when I do *order by date* I get 01.01.1970 dates. But the date I select returns everything as it should.

PHP what I use to get data from Oracle DB:

```
$s = oci_parse($conn, 'select ADRESS, DATE from IECERES_VW order by DATE desc fetch first 10 rows only');
oci_set_prefetch($s, 7);
oci_execute($s);
$results = array();
while($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {     $result[] = $row; }
```

This is how the output code looks like:

```
<td nowrap class="text-center p-1"><?php echo date("d.m.Y",strtotime($row['DATE'])); ?></td>
<td  nowrap class="text-center p-1"><?php echo "-"; ?></td>
<td  nowrap class="text-center p-1"><?php echo $row['ADRESS']; ?></td>
```

I tried multiple date functions with oracle but all do the same, date is just not sort correctly.

Comment: What is that column's datatype? If it is DATE, then ORDER BY works OK. Otherwise, if it is VARCHAR2 (usually a big mistake), then it is sorted as a string so you'd have to apply TO_DATE function with appropriate format mask (e.g. TO_DATE(date_column, 'dd.mm.yyyy')).

Comment: Data type is Date, I checked it right now to be sure. And this is the wierd thing because I made similar program a month ago with select and sort by date query and all worked good. And that program used Oracle database too and most of the rows are the same as I am using now included date row.

Comment: in which format date is stored in your database's DATE column ?

Comment: @RonakDhoot I am not sure, how can I check this using SQL_Developer ?

Comment: sample data stored in DATE column ?

Comment: Ahh. Sorry. Stored like this 2010.03.19  (Ymd)

Comment: @RonakDhoot - if the data type is DATE, the "format" it is stored in is oracle's internal, binary format.  "format" only applies when dealing with character string representations of that date.  Even if you just do a simple 'select date_column from my_table', there will be an implied TO_CHAR function applied when returning that to the requesting client, for display purposes.

Comment: Hey @EdStevens Thanks for answering. Maybe you have idea how to solve this ? Because I am stuck on this problem and have no idea what else I can do or check.

Comment: I don't speak PHP, so am little to no help there.  What I _do_ know is that if you have a column of type DATE and your query includes an ORDER BY on that column, then oracle _will_ return the data correctly sorted as you specified.  Now, if at some point down stream you see that data NOT sorted by date, I'll bet you dollars to donuts that your processing of what oracle returned included some more sorting - perhaps on the charater string representation of that DATE.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But when I delete the order by part all works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

After few day's of trouble I manage to find where to problem is.  Someone had enter dates with Null values and as there are millions of data in table I didnt even consider to check the values as I assume all was correct.
This simple problem took so much time. But thanks to everyone who gave some good ideas too.